# C++ return types and type names

Tags: c++, qualified-name

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct H
{
    static const int Index = 0;
};

struct V
{
    static const int Index = 1;
};

struct Slice
{
    Slice(): Value(5) { }

    int Value;
};

class Dimension
{
public:

    template<class D>
    Slice& Slice() // causes compiler error
    //::Slice& Slice() // compiles ok
    {
        return std::get<D::Index>(slices);
    }

    template<class D>
    ::Slice const& Slice() const
    {
        return std::get<D::Index>(slices);
    }

private:

    typedef std::tuple<::Slice, ::Slice> SlicesT;
    SlicesT slices;
};


int main(int, char*[])
{
    Dimension d;

    std::cout << d.Slice<V>().Value << std::endl;

    d.Slice<V>().Value = 10; // error here

    std::cout << d.Slice<V>().Value << std::endl;
}
```

That gives this error in VS2012: `error C3892: 'd' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const`

I can fix it by qualifying the first function return type (as in the commented out line). But I don't really understand what's going on here. Is this a compiler bug or is it genuinely dangerous code?

Comment: You have to qualify with the `::` because you have a function with the same name as the type.

Comment: @Adam Yes. I guess I was just surprised that the compiler finds the function name and hides the type name before it gets to the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clang` gives a much friendlier warning:

```
main.cpp:33:5: error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'Slice' in this scope
    Slice const& Slice() const
    ^
    struct 
main.cpp:26:12: note: struct 'Slice' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'Slice' here
    Slice& Slice() // causes compiler error
           ^
1 error generated.
```

`struct Slice` or `::Slice` both work in letting the compiler know you mean the type. On MSVC, for some reason, `struct Slice` doesn't work, so you must use the scope resolution operator.